# CTRL key and arrow keys allow in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" id="s" />
jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur',function()
{ 
    var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
    selectedInput.val( selectedInput.val().replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/g, '' ) );
});
```

I want to edit my text from anywhere in the text so I want the arrow keys (<kbd>left</kbd>,<kbd>right</kbd>,<kbd>up</kbd>,<kbd>down</kbd>) and plus <kbd>crtl</kbd> key to select all the text with <kbd>ctrl+A</kbd>.

Comment: could you be a little clearer about what you want it to do and what it's doing wrong now?

Comment: i just want to add a text in anywhere in the input. for example: hello my world. i want to edit my text between hello and my but i can't because I only allowed characters,numbers,and comma in the input. I want to include arrow keys and ctrl key as well but i don't know how to\

Comment: What actually your problem? It working fine which you expected?

Comment: wait i am creating a js fiddle to show my problem

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw007t8/ now write some text and press ctrl+A and see what happens and also move between the text with the arrow keys

Comment: split the keyup handling -> for key validation, and blur handling for replacing invalid keys.... that way you wont interfere with default arrow key and ctrl+a behavior. Note: changing the value programmatically resets the cursor so it wont be good for your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add `\s` to your regex to allow spaces. Do nothing on left and right keypress.

I have removed the `keyup` event to avoid the annoying behaviour

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var allowedKeyCodes = [17, 37, 39];

jQuery('#s').bind('blur',function(event){ 
  if($.inArray(event.keyCode, allowedKeyCodes))
    return false;
  var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
  selectedInput.val( selectedInput.val().replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9,\s]/g, '' ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="s" value="Hello World"/>
```

Comment: no no i just want these thing in the input: a-z,A-Z,0-9,comma, arrow keys and ctrl key

Comment: thats why i am using jquery above

Comment: @HassanAli Checkout my updated answer above. Test it by entering `My` in the middle of the text, also add something like `--` andwere and try clicking outside in the whitespace to see the code work. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I add keyup in your code and remove the \s space. Its working very good for the arrow keys left and right. I will add the up and down keys myself and whats the code of the ctrl key?

Comment: @HassanAli FYI http://mikemurko.com/general/jquery-keycode-cheatsheet/

Comment: Id recommend declaring an array and using inArray to check for the keycodes, that way keys can be added or removed from the list easily

Comment: @DelightedD0D I like your suggestion. Answer updated!

Comment: @HassanAli Answer updated as per DelightedD0D's suggestion. This will make it very easy to add/remove keycodes.

Answer (score 2):

just Add if condition in your code and it will work, Following is working code. Let me know for any further help.

```
jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur',function()
 { 
  var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
  if (selectedInput.val().match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/g)) {      
    selectedInput.val( selectedInput.val().replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/g, '' )   );
 }
});
```

Here, is the jsfiddle link for your answer http://jsfiddle.net/ug1srcm6/

Comment: thanks thats working pretty fine also.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to limit which keys will call the function

```js
jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur',function(e)
{ 
  var keys=[37, 38, 39, 40];
  // for any special keys you want to ignore
  // add their keycodes to this array
  // left arrow:     37
  // up arrow:   38
  // right arrow:    39
  // down arrow:     40
  
  // then, only call your function if the key press is not one of these keys
  if($.inArray(e.keyCode, keys ) == -1 ){
    var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
    selectedInput.val( selectedInput.val().replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9,]/g, '' ) );
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="s" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For **ctrl + a** try following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, aKey = 86

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) 
           ctrlDown = true;
    }).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) 
          ctrlDown = false;
    });

    $(".select-all").keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == aKey)) 
           return false;
    });
});
```

for arrow key use following key code:

```
left arrow:     37

up arrow:   38

right arrow:    39

down arrow:     40
```

Answer (score 0):

For ctrl + a I recommend you to use mechanism like this:
https://github.com/adrianmalik/jquery-hotkeys
Then you will be able to do in example:

```
$('input').hotkey('ctrl+a', function() { /* Here you can do what you want */ });
```

Comment: the OP wants to limit which chars are allowed in an input box to just letters and numbers, his current regex does this but will not allow him to press the keys `ctrl+a`, `left`, `right`, etc.. because when you do, it replaces the text in the input and by default the browser moves the cursor to the end of the replaced text negating the movement